# Not able to call function on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following div in which I have several list item.

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="MyController" class="my-controller">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li class = "active">
                <a href="#legislate" ng-click="getLegislators()" ><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Legislators</a>
            </li>
```

Then I have the getLegislator() function defined as below:-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
    myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'getData.php',
            params: {value: 'legislator'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            legislators = response.data.results;
        });
        $scope.getLegislator=function(){
            $scope.users = []
            $scope.house = []
            $scope.senate = []
```

Which does other tasks too. The thing is that when I click on the list item the function call does not happen. I am pretty new to this, dont know what I am doing wrong. My objective is to run the function when the list item is clicked.

Comment: getLegislator !== getLegislators

Comment: Really sorry for the silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function name inside 'ng-click' is 'getLegislators()'. But in the controller you are written '$scope.getLegislator'. Remove 's' added at the end in the template ng-click function